# How to add an external component to StoryBoard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to add this https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow to my project. The author said "Add ImageSlideshow view to your view hiearchy either in Interface Builder or in code."

But after I installed it on pod, I didn't see it available in the object library which makes me able to add this component. How to add it? I am really new to iOS development and I don't understand the way they talk...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add UIView in storyboard where you want to display ImageSlideshow and set UIView class to ImageSlideshow as follows in the images.

[image]

to

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Drag an `UIView` onto your storyboard and then in the Identity Inspector, enter the custom class name.

Answer (score 1):

I think you made some wrong steps while installing pod.

Step1: First open your terminal and type cd your project path.
Example:
**UNTITLED:~ apple$ cd /Volumes/DATAPART/My/My_Learnings/July_2017_iOS11/SampleRoundedView**

Step2: Create a pod file with pod init command.
Example:
**UNTITLED:SampleRoundedView apple$ pod init**

Step3: Open pod file and add pod reference.
         **pod 'ImageSlideshow', '~> 1.3'**

Save and close your pod file.

Step4: type install pod in terminal.
Example:
       **UNTITLED:SampleRoundedView apple$ pod install**

Then close your Xcode and open with Xcodeworkspace file.
Then follow solution provided by venkat.